# Deciding whether given infinite series converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am self-learning Real Analysis from `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abbott. I am having some trouble determining the convergence or divergence of the below infinite series. I have some initial thoughts which I have put down. Any inputs would be really helpful.

How do I build more skill at finding out if a given infinite series is convergent/divergent?

Exercise 2.7.2

> (c) $1 - \frac{3}{4} + \frac{4}{6} - \frac{5}{8} + \frac{6}{10} - \frac{7}{12} + \ldots$

> (d) $1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9} + \ldots$

> (e) $1 - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6^2} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8^2} + \ldots$

***Proof.***

(c) Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence of partial sums of the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.

The general expression for the infinite series is,

\begin{align*}
1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\cdot\frac{n+2}{2n}
\end{align*}

I cannot apply the alternate series test, because
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+2}{2n} = \frac{1}{2} \ne 0
\end{align*}

I can't think of a known convergent or divergent series to compare with, in order to use the Alternate Series test.

(d) One observation is, this is not a rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: **[Note]** : If the limit condition of the Alternate Series Test fails, then the series diverges by $n^{th}$ Term Test and you should know why.

Comment: I don't quite know why. 

In the proof of Alternating Series Test, if $(s_n)$ is the sequence of the partial sums of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n $, we know that,  $\lvert{s_n - s_m}\rvert \le a_{m+1}$. If the $n$th term test fails, this distance cannot be made smaller than $\epsilon$ and the sequence is not Cauchy. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @GAUSS1860, Abbott's book does not explicitly mention anything called the *n*th term test.

Comment: You simply look at your original series as a whole without even considering alternate series test. You should see that by the algebraic properties of limits we have that both $(-1)^{n}$ and $\frac{n+2}{2n}$ have their limit product different from zero.

Comment: Originally, the $n^{th}$ Term Test is the contrapositive statement of "If $\sum a_{n}$ converges then $a_{n}\to0$"

Comment: stewart calculus has a section called something like strategy for testing series. i think this sums up the strategies of the preceding sections and also gives tips on what to look out for and in what order to look out for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(c) Your series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{2n}$ and, since you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{2n}=0$, the series diverges.

(d) The sum of the first $3$ terms is greater than $1$. The sum of the first $6$ terms is greater than $1+\frac14$. The sum of the first $9$ terms is greater than $1+\frac14+\frac17$. So, your series diverges.

(e) The sum of the positive terms diverges, whereas the sum of the negative terms converges, and therefore this series diverges.

Comment: I think in $(c)$ you should say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+2}{2n}=0$ instead of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n+2}{2n}=0$.

Comment: @GAUSS1860 Why is that?

Comment: Ahh, never mind I see you skipped showing the failure of the limit condition of the alternate series test.

Comment: @GAUSS1860 No, that is **not** what I did. I used the fact that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ converges}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0.$$

Comment: I do acknowledge that! But what I meant is you didn't precisely show how  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n+2}{2n}\neq0$ for the OP to understand but no worries everything is clear now :)

Comment: For e the sum of the positive terms converges, which tells us the series diverges.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can I also use Cauchy condensation test to prove  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n-2} = 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} + \ldots$ diverges? I observed $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n a_{2^n} =1+\frac{2}{4} + \frac{4}{10} + \frac{8}{22} + \frac{16}{46} + \ldots$. The general term $\frac{2^n}{3\cdot 2^n - 2}$ approaches $1/3$, as $n \to \infty$. So, by $n$th term test, this guy diverges.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, Okay, I convinced myself, that any harmonic series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a+(n-1)d}$ diverges.